# Selected Numbers to Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am having trouble creating a Text box where the user can enter which numbers to select.. Eg. `10-16,18,22-30` (Like when you select which pages to print) however, I have some letters thrown into it also, for example it may go `11,11A,12,12A`.

How do I do this so that when the user has typed which numbers they want, it is transferred to an array?

I'm not very good at explaining things, so sorry if you don't understand.

Comment: 11,11A,12,12A, 15-18 should then be converted to [11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18] ?

Comment: What should be array elements for input of `10-16,18,22-30`? What data type should be the array?

Comment: Sorry No, it would still need to be 11,11A,12,12A.

Comment: But if the user typed, for example, 11-15,19.. THe array would go, 11,11A,12,12A,13,14,15,19

Comment: If I type `11-12`, would that result in `11,11A,12` or `11,11A,12,12A`? Do you have the available numbers and number-letter combinations available somewhere, like in an array?

Comment: Just add an example with one specific given input and its expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Without input error checking  and assuming Numbers with letters can not define range it can look like

```
        String textInput = "11,11A,12,12A,13-16,18,22-30";
        String[] strArray = textInput.Split(',');
        List<String> pages = new List<String>();
        foreach (String s in strArray)
        {
            String[] range = s.Split('-');
            if (range.Length == 2)
            {
                int startPage = int.Parse(range[0]);
                int endPage = int.Parse(range[1]);
                for (int i = startPage; i<= endPage; i++)
                {
                    pages.Add(i.ToString());
                    pages.Add(i.ToString()+"A");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                pages.Add(s);
            }
        }

        String[] resultArray = pages.ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Input: " + textInput);
        foreach (String s in resultArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the numeric part from the alphabetical. Then you could use this linq query:

```
var txtRange = "16,18,22-30";
var tokens = txtRange.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
.Select(t => new { 
    Token = t, 
    Range =  t.Split(new[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
})
.Select(x => new{ x.Token, x.Range, 
    RangeStart = int.Parse(x.Range[0]),
    RangeEnd = x.Range.Length > 1 ? int.Parse(x.Range[1]) : int.Parse(x.Range[0])
});

int min = tokens.Min(x => x.RangeStart);
int max = tokens.Max(x => x.RangeEnd);

var list = new List<String>() { "11", "11A", "12", "12A", "13", "14", "15", "19" };

var result = list.Select(s => new
{
    Str = s,
    Num = int.Parse(new string(s.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()))
})
.Where(x => x.Num >= min && x.Num <= max);

foreach(var x in result)
    Console.WriteLine("String: {0} Numeric-Part: {1}", x.Str, x.Num);
```

It's working (although it seems a bit overcomplicated).

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/GSFCEG)